# How to give default value of 0 to all the empty cells in Handsontable?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have a simple handsontable, which get its data from a database, but not all the cells will have data,some will have just null values. Instead of handsontable showing the empty cell in the table, is it possible to put a number formatter with values like 0.00 by default??

Comment: might be good to make a http://jsfiddle.net just so we can see how far you've got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is solution. please check and let me know if not working. i have tested it on jsfiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/yL8t1psf/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var container = document.getElementById('basic_example');

  var data = [
      ['', 'Kia', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda'],
      ['2014', 10, 11, 12, 13],
      ['2015', 20, null, , 13],
      ['2016', null, 15,'', null]
  ];

  var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data,
    height: 396,
    colHeaders: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    stretchH: 'all',
    columnSorting: true,
    contextMenu: true,
    cells: function (row, col, prop,value) {
      var cellProperties = {};          
          cellProperties.renderer = firstRowRenderer;
      return cellProperties;
    }
  });

});


  function firstRowRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    if(!value || value === '' || value == null ) {                        
        td.innerHTML = "0.00";
    }    
  }
```

Comment: if statement should be, if(!value || value === '') or it won't work

Comment: It will work please check my edited answer. i have also updated jsfiddle link.

Comment: How can I get this default value on submit?? It returns "null"

Answer (score 1):

Add this into your conditional formatting.

http://docs.handsontable.com/0.20.0/demo-conditional-formatting.html

```
if (!value || value === '') {
  td.innerHTML = "0.00";
}
```

Comment: what if `value=0` or a boolean?

Comment: @AndrewBone,thanks for the solution,I was using the same logic,but was assigning the 0.00 to value itself and not td.innerHTML.